# How to declare and use the namespace of one class into another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I Have created two .cs files with namespaces ,classes and methods . I want to call the classes of one .cs file into another .cs file. Can u help me how to declare namespace and use the namespace so that i can call the classes of the preceding .cs file.

Please forgive if my explanation is not correct.

Suppose i have the following code.

ClassFile1

```
using system

namespace namespace1
{
   class c1
   {
     Methods()    
   }
}
```

ClassFile2

```
using system
//here i need to declare the namespace1 .Can u help me how to declare namespace1 in this ClassFile2//

namespace namespace2
{
   class c2
     {
       Methods()
     }
}
```

Comment: Why is it downnvote . I am a beginner in C#.

Comment: @user3027039 It is because of *bad question*. You could have posted a few concrete code and asked a specific question.

Comment: While I didn't give you the down vote, I am guessing it is because this is a pretty easy thing to look up online. Try reading this http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson06 . Essentially you just need to add "using SomeNamespace" to your class file.

Comment: Thanks L.B , bsayegh , Anthony Raymond.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the fully-qualified name of the class:

```
namespace SecondNamespace
{
    public class SecondClass
    {
        private FirstNamespace.FirstClass someObject;
    }
}
```

Or you can add a `using` directive to the file (note, this is at the *file* level, not the *class* level) to include a specific namespace when resolving type names:

```
using FirstNamespace;

namespace SecondNamespace
{
    public class SecondClass
    {
        private FirstClass someObject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx):

```
namespace SampleNamespace
{
    class SampleClass
    {
        public void SampleMethod()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(
              "SampleMethod inside SampleNamespace");
        }
    }

    // Create a nested namespace, and define another class. 
    namespace NestedNamespace
    {
        class SampleClass
        {
            public void SampleMethod()
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(
                  "SampleMethod inside NestedNamespace");
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Displays "SampleMethod inside SampleNamespace."
            SampleClass outer = new SampleClass();
            outer.SampleMethod();

            // Displays "SampleMethod inside SampleNamespace."
            SampleNamespace.SampleClass outer2 = new SampleNamespace.SampleClass();
            outer2.SampleMethod();

            // Displays "SampleMethod inside NestedNamespace."
            NestedNamespace.SampleClass inner = new NestedNamespace.SampleClass();
            inner.SampleMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note also that sometimes in addition to the "using" entry (I'm not quite clear on how you app is structured, if it's all one project this is probably moot) you may also need to add the reference.  Also not sure what environment you're using.  From VSExpress while in the project/file that's the recipient click on Project - Add Reference, select solution and then select your namespace.